# DB4O: limit a query by range

Tags: java, db4o

Is it possible to get a query result by a interval?

I was think something like that:

```
List<Object> getRangeQuery(Object example, int beginIndex, int endIndex){
    ObjectSet<Object> set = db.queryByExample(example);
    return set.subList(beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

My intention is to fill a table where I gonna limit the list by "pages". But I think that way won't perform well.

How far I've researched I didn't find a way to do it natively.Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way yes. There is not explicit limit operation.

The query result (`ObjectSet`) is a lazy loaded result. It will only load the objects and ranges requested. So, it will only load the range of the sub-list you requested.